# Syntax Error in PHP API

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am developing an android app and I need to have an PHP API in order for my app to talk to SQL Database.

I am having error parsing to JSON on `getJarrayFromString();`

I then tried to Log the actual error and it was as follows:

```
03-24 15:41:12.175: E/JustDealsUtils(480): Error parsing to json on getJarrayFromString(); org.json.JSONException: Value Database of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
03-24 15:41:12.175: E/log_tag(480): Failed data was:
03-24 15:41:12.175: E/log_tag(480): Database query failed You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bCode` LIKE '%%' AND `bTitle` LIKE '%%' AND `bModule` LIKE '%%'' at line 1
```

Now above log clarifies very well that error lies in my `books.php` API which is as follows:

```
<?php
    include("MysqlConnection.php");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $from = $_POST["from"];
    $nr = $_POST["nr"];
    // those variables are for search
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $code = $_POST["code"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];
    $module = $_POST["module"];
    $order = $_POST["order"];
    $by = $_POST["by"];


    $sql = "SET CHARACTER SET utf8";
    $db->query($sql);

    if(isset($from) && isset($nr)){
        // we need to know how many rows are in total for this query
<PROBLEM IS HERE---> $sql = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `bSpecialOffer`='false' AND `bCode` LIKE '%$code%' AND `bTitle` LIKE '%$title%' AND `bModule` LIKE '%$module%'";
        $query = $db->query($sql);

        $rows = array();
        $rows[] = array("numRows"=>$db->numRows($query));

        // if those 2 var are set then we order the query after them
        if(isset($order) && isset($by)){
            $sql .= " ORDER BY `$order` $by LIMIT $from, $nr";
        }else{
            $sql .= "LIMIT $from, $nr";
        }

        $query = $db->query($sql);

        if($db->numRows($query)!=0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $rows[] =  $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($rows);
        }
    }

    $db->closeConnection();
?>
```

I am confused how my statement is wrong in PHP as mentioned above in Log Cat!

Is there another way of writing the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `bSpecialOffer`='false' AND `bCode` LIKE '%$code%' AND `bTitle` LIKE '%$title%' AND `bModule` LIKE '%$module%'";
```

Your suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Definitely learn about prepared statements, because your code is a perfect candidate for a SQL injection attck.

Comment: Also, canonical link: [Why upgrade from the mysql API](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2012/php-mysql-why-to-upgrade-extmysql/). Please consider using PDO or the mysqli_ functions (and use prepared statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql query is so far correct but the value that you're passing are empty.

The value of

```
    $code = $_POST["code"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];
    $module = $_POST["module"];
```

are empty. Try to make sure that the value are setted.

sometime the double quote are responsable for that. then try to replace them with a single quote

```
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $module = $_POST['module'];
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply. Would you like to be a bit more collaborative, I mean how values are meant to be settled?

Comment: I am only using `$code` `$price` and `$module` to perform search functions in my app and they work fine within my app.

Comment: @OliverSmith-Jones 1. make sure that you provide the right parameter by request. 2. try to replace  $_POST["..."] with $_POST['...'];

Comment: Passing empty variables will not cause problems.

Comment: @OliverSmith-Jones please post your java code u use to send the resquest

Comment: @DreamEater Not having a space before "LIMIT" does, tho. And this is only hit by not having those $_POST variables are null.

Comment: @Festus Tamakloe As per your suggestion, I changed double quotes to single quotes and the error now is slightly different. Now it gives `03-24 16:11:23.534: E/log_tag(480): Database query failed Unknown column 'false' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @OliverSmith-Jones is the data type of bSpecialOffer a boolean or string?

Comment: @Festus Tamakloe It is a String.

Comment: @OliverSmith-Jones just to try: please remove `bSpecialOffer`='false' AND and try it again

Comment: @Festus Tamakloe Your solution worked like a miracle. Thanks very much for your time and suggestions.